# Kotlin, вопрос по function reference

Tags: kotlin, lambda

Долго вчитывался в документацию, но не до конца понял, как оно работает.

Внутренний голос нашептывает, что вот эти две строки должны делать одно и то-же:

```
private fun makePost(post: Map<String, String>): RequestBody {
    val body = FormBody.Builder()
1:    post.forEach { (k, v) -> body.add(k, v) }
2:    post.forEach { body::add }
    return body.build()
}
```

Но не делают. первая работает, а вторая нет (body остается пустым, но и ошибок нет)

растолкуйте, пожалуйста, где мой внутренний голос облажался и можно ли(как?) использовать тут `function reference`?

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться версией `Kotlin`, что вы используете?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja последней, которая плагином в андроид студию подтягивается. 1.1.2-3

Comment: Уверены что в `build.gradle` именно эта версия? Плагин-плагином, а вдруг не подтягивается? :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja конечно уверен. `ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-3'`, `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`? `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"`

Comment: Ваш внутренний голос прав, по моему мнению, см. ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ разработчиков:

> Your code is incorrect. To pass a method reference to a function, you
>   need to enclose it in parentheses, not in curly braces:
>   bar.forEach(foo1::add)

При передаче (method)function reference в функцию необходимо использовать обычные скобки, а не фигурные.

Следующие три строки выполняют одно и то же:

```
post.forEach ({ (k, v) -> body.add(k, v) })
post.forEach { (k, v) -> body.add(k, v) }
post.forEach (body::add)
```

Обратите внимание, что метод, на который осуществляется ссылка, должен возвращать `Unit`, иначе даже не скомпилируется.

Если единственным параметром является лямбда, то обычные скобки можно опустить и оставить только фигурные (строки 1 и 2)

Comment: Интересно. А не известно ли, как интерпретируются фигурные скобки в таком случае?

Comment: @yeputons обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Отлично, что с версией все ясно. Вот мое обьяснение:

Метод `forEach` для вашей `Map` оперирует элементами `Map.Entry<String, String>`, а это не то же самое, что два параметра типа `String`, необходимые методу `body::add`.
Но `Kotlin` вместо того, чтобы ругнуться, делает вид что сможет развернуть элемент, как делает в варианте №1, но что-то не получается.

Думаю, что можете зарепортить им баг. Как минимум на то, что нет ни ошибки, ни предупреждения, но код не работает.

Вот ссылка на имплементацию этой фичи.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6947

Это похоже на специфический кейс для `Map`, который упустили в тестах новой фичи.

Comment: Ответ разработчиков:
`Your code is incorrect. To pass a method reference to a function, you need to enclose it in parentheses, not in curly braces:

bar.forEach(foo1::add)`

Comment: Все равно это баг, `post.forEach { body::add }` не должен компилиться тогда.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17053

Comment: По сути это совершенно нормальное поведение языка, вводящее в заблуждение неочевидностью синтаксиса. Фактически создается ничего не делающая лямбда

Comment: Отлично, в 1.1.3 проверим :)